# Spring autowire anotation in jmeter

Tags: java, spring, jmeter, junit4, performance-testing

I am trying to run some performance test cases on an spring application using jmeter.
I know that in jmeter, spring annotation would not work, like for example

```
@ContextConfiguration and @Autowired
```

which I over came by getting the ApplicationContext and then getting the Bean.

But, is there any other work around  because I have a very big Base class which has lot of

```
@Autowired instance variables and lot of dependencies.
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with JMeter but I think you can treat your JMeter test cases as a standalone Spring application in which you load the ApplicationContext once then all your Spring Beans will be available.

See this tread: [Using Spring 3 autowire in a standalone Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659720/using-spring-3-autowire-in-a-standalone-java-application)

Hope this helps.