# How use @Autowired with Annotation config?

Tags: java, spring

i create simple spring project and i need to use annotation `@Autowired` but when i run project, i get exception `NullPointerException`.

This is my classes:

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    @Autowired
    private static InjectClass injectClass;

    public static void setInjectClass(InjectClass injectClass) {
        Main.injectClass = injectClass;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        injectClass.hello();    //NullPointerException
    }
}
```

**ConfigurationBean**

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationBean {
    @Bean
    public InjectClass injectClass(){
        return new InjectClass();
    }
}
```

**InjectClass**

```
public class InjectClass {
    public void hello(){
        System.out.println("Autowired success!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to understand how Spring works. Review some tutorials. Spring isn't magic. It also doesn't work well with anything static.

Comment: pls put link to tutorial when show how work from annotation config.

Comment: You need to create application context. Please Follow this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659720/using-spring-3-autowire-in-a-standalone-java-application

Comment: @Subbu, thank you, this is work! but how use `@Autowiring` without `ApplicationContext` this is real?

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initiate application contex before using any bean.
You can do it by writing following code in starting of your main method.
     AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
      ConfigurationBean.class);

Comment: i need use `@Autowired` !

Comment: @BohdanOlehovich which is why you need an  **Annotation**ConfigApplicationContext.

Comment: Because AnnotationConfigApplicationContext is the one who is responsible to initialize all beans defined in configuration class. If you will not create inctance of AnnotationConfigApplicationContext, no bean will be initialized and you will always get null for all beans.