# `NullPointerException` due to failed autowiring

Tags: java, spring, autowired, properties-file

I refactored the [Spring doc for creating batch service](http://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing) to implement a stand alone class of my reader

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:db-config.properties")
public class CsvReader<Item> extends FlatFileItemReader<Item>{

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  public CsvReader() {
    this.setResource(new ClassPathResource(env.getProperty("csv_file.name")));
    this.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<ImportDataItem>() {
      {
        setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {
          {
            setNames(new String[] { "firstName", "lastName" });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

`NullPointerException`is thrown by `env.getProperty("csv_file.name")` and if it is replaced with a `String` of filename, it works. I've read [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3659854/3381334) & the above code looks good, so could you please help me understand why `Environment env` isn't autowired?

```
[main] INFO org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5c29bfd: startup date [Thu Oct 22 11:26:18 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
[main] INFO org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Skipping bean definition for [BeanMethod:name=importDataJob,declaringClass=batch.spring.example.job.ImportDataJob]: a definition for bean 'importDataJob' already exists. This top-level bean definition is considered as an override.
[main] WARN org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer - @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.stepScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
[main] WARN org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer - @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.jobScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
[main] WARN org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CsvReader' defined in batch.spring.example.job.ImportDataJob: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader]: Factory method 'CsvReader' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
  at batch.spring.example.ImportDataApp.main(ImportDataApp.java:24)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader]: Factory method 'CsvReader' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
  ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at batch.spring.example.job.item_reader.CsvReader.<init>(CsvReader.java:28)
  at batch.spring.example.job.ImportDataJob.CsvReader(ImportDataJob.java:67)
  at batch.spring.example.job.ImportDataJob$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eb882444.CGLIB$CsvReader$1(<generated>)
  at batch.spring.example.job.ImportDataJob$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eb882444$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6d548885.invoke(<generated>)
  at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
  at batch.spring.example.job.ImportDataJob$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eb882444.CsvReader(<generated>)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
  ... 14 more
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CsvReader' defined in batch.spring.example.job.ImportDataJob: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader]: Factory method 'CsvReader' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
  at batch.spring.example.ImportDataApp.main(ImportDataApp.java:24)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader]: Factory method 'CsvReader' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
  ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at batch.spring.example.job.item_reader.CsvReader.<init>(CsvReader.java:28)
  at batch.spring.example.job.ImportDataJob.CsvReader(ImportDataJob.java:67)
  at batch.spring.example.job.ImportDataJob$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eb882444.CGLIB$CsvReader$1(<generated>)
  at batch.spring.example.job.ImportDataJob$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eb882444$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6d548885.invoke(<generated>)
  at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
  at batch.spring.example.job.ImportDataJob$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eb882444.CsvReader(<generated>)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.inv    [main] INFO org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5c29bfd: startup date [Thu Oct 22 11:26:18 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
[main] INFO org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Skipping bean definition for [BeanMethod:name=importDataJob,declaringClass=batch.spring.example.job.ImportDataJob]: a definition for bean 'importDataJob' already exists. This top-level bean definition is considered as an override.
[main] WARN org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer - @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.stepScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
[main] WARN org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer - @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.jobScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
[main] WARN org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CsvReader' defined in batch.spring.example.job.ImportDataJob: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader]: Factory method 'CsvReader' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
  at batch.spring.example.ImportDataApp.main(ImportDataApp.java:24)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader]: Factory method 'CsvReader' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
  ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at batch.spring.example.job.item_reader.CsvReader.<init>(CsvReader.java:28)
  at batch.spring.example.job.ImportDataJob.CsvReader(ImportDataJob.java:67)
  at batch.spring.example.job.ImportDataJob$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eb882444.CGLIB$CsvReader$1(<generated>)
  at batch.spring.example.job.ImportDataJob$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eb882444$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6d548885.invoke(<generated>)
  at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
  at batch.spring.example.job.ImportDataJob$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eb882444.CsvReader(<generated>)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
  ... 14 more
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CsvReader' defined in batch.spring.example.job.ImportDataJob: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader]: Factory method 'CsvReader' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
  at batch.spring.example.ImportDataApp.main(ImportDataApp.java:24)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader]: Factory method 'CsvReader' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
  ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at batch.spring.example.job.item_reader.CsvReader.<init>(CsvReader.java:28)
  at batch.spring.example.job.ImportDataJob.CsvReader(ImportDataJob.java:67)
  at batch.spring.example.job.ImportDataJob$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eb882444.CGLIB$CsvReader$1(<generated>)
  at batch.spring.example.job.ImportDataJob$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eb882444$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6d548885.invoke(<generated>)
  at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
  at batch.spring.example.job.ImportDataJob$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eb882444.CsvReader(<generated>)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
  ... 14 more
```

Comment: could you share Environment source and context.xml with us?

Comment: Also why you have file type csv before filename in `env.getProperty("csv.filename")` shouldn't it be `env.getProperty("filename.csv")`?

Comment: @AmirAl The property contains the filename of the csv file. The second option would be confusing, since it looks like there's a file named `filename.csv` instead of a property.

Comment: @Kayaman oh okay then that explains the whole thing regarding naming. I thought it would read file based on it's name and type, but it looks like that you are indicating a property name :)

Comment: @AmirAl, just to improve readability, I changed `csv.filename` to `csv_file.name` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all boils down to how objects are constructed and autowired. To construct an object, one must call the constructor. Then you have a reference to the object, and can set its fields. That's what Spring is doing when creating beans and autowiring them: it calls the constructor, and then sets all the fields annotated with `@Autowired`. It can't set a field before calling the constructor, since it wouldn't have any object yet.

But your constructor tries to access the fields, that are supposed to have been autowired by Spring, before the object was even constructed. That can't possibly happen.

To access an autowired bean from a constructor, constructor injection must be used. Another option would be to move all this code from the constructor to a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: Thanks @jb-nizet, adding @ComponentScan("batch.spring.example") solved the error :)