# Access java arguments in spring standalone application

Tags: java, spring

I am creating a standalone application using spring annotations.
I have used the following link to refer [Using Spring 3 autowire in a standalone Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659720/using-spring-3-autowire-in-a-standalone-java-application)

My question is how do I access java arguments in my standalone application ?

Comment: Accepted answer shows how to use parameters. You instantiate Spring context, get beans you need and call their methods passing parameters you need.

Comment: Your application will still accept arguments through the `main` method. You just pass them along...